# IE only anglure http request cache / MVC issue

Tags: angularjs

I have some code that loads a list from a MVC controller.

I load the data with

```
$scope.loadData = function () {        
    $scope.promise = myhttp = $http.get("forms");
    myhttp.success(function (response) {
        $scope.rows = response;
```

This works fine, the data loads and I can see the data on my html page.

But, if I reload with code, eg I just run $scope.loadData again, it fails in IE.

Works in Chrome, FF 
Fails in IE and Spartan (Tested on non windows 10 same issue)

The headers look like

```
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
```

The MVC controller has the authorise attribute hence the s-maxage=0, this prevents the proxy from caching.

I have tried

```
$scope.promise = myhttp = $http.get("forms");
```

When I fiddle, i dont see the request going to the server but the code does get fired.

If I nav to a new page and nav back it does reload fresh data as you would expect. It just when the reload is done with $http

Thanks

*EDIT*

Post works, eg

```
$scope.promise = myhttp = $http.post("forms");
```

Comment: as I was typing this, i thought ... mmmm what if I post, post does the trick :) but still why this unexpected behavior in IE. I should load the data.

Comment: In which version of IE and which version of angular you are using?

Comment: Did you try by adding polyfills ?

Comment: not tried polyfills, tbh the `post` works and I cannot see an issue with the work around. I never need to cache etc so its cool. But thanks for taking time to read my Q.

Comment: Try with by setting header 'Cache-Control' as 'no-cache'

Comment: no-cache is a HTTP 1.0 directive that was retained in HTTP 1.1 for backward. 

*maxage* This is the HTTP 1.1 equivalent of the earlier Expires header available in HTTP 1.0. It implicitly tells the browser it may cache the page, but must re-validate with the server if the max-age is exceeded. Setting max-age to zero ensures that a page is never served from cache, but is always re-validated against the server. 

https://web.archive.org/web/20140811162719/http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/